# Behaviour of special variables under macro expansion

Tags: macros, common-lisp, special-variables

```
FUZZ> (defvar *foo* nil)
*FOO*
FUZZ> (defmacro bar ()
        (format t "foo: ~A" *foo*)
        `(+ 1 1))
BAR
FUZZ> (defmacro bot ()
        (let ((*foo* 17))
          `(bar)))
BOT
FUZZ> (bot)
foo: NIL
```

My mental model (clearly wrong) of macro expansion says the following happens in order:

Run the macro expansion of `bot` (which binds `*foo*` to `17`), run the macro expansion of `bar`, which prints the current value of `*foo*` (being `17`), and returns the form `(+ 1 1)`, which is not a macro, macro expansion time is now over, finally evaluate the form `(+ 1 1)`, and returns `2`.

Why am I wrong?

Is there an easy way to do what I intend?

Comment: Ahhh, so my mistake was to think of the binding of `*foo*` like a dynamical variable, in effect for all the **time** it took to macroexpand `(bar)` and (crucially) all the forms it becomes in turn.  Whereas in fact, once `(bar)` is returned, we are done with `*foo*`, as Joshua makes clear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the REPL is told to evaluate `(bot)`, it first has to perform macroexpansion.  It calls the macroexpansion function `bot`, which means, in effect, evaluating

```
(let ((*foo* 17))
  `(bar))
```

That returns `(bar)` and then the binding of from `let` is unwound.  Now we've got `(bar)`.  `bar` is a macro, so it's time for another round of macroexpansion, which means evaluating

```
(progn 
  (format t "foo: ~a" *foo*)
  `(+ 1 1))
```

which prints `foo: NIL`, and returns `(+ 1 1)`.

If you want the macroexpansion to be performed in the scope of some bindings, you'll need to call the macroexpansion function yourself.  E.g., you can use [**macroexpand**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm):

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *foo* nil)
*FOO*
CL-USER> (defmacro bar ()
           (format t "foo: ~a" *foo*)
           `(+ 1 1))
BAR
CL-USER> (defmacro baz ()
           (let ((*foo* 42))
             (macroexpand '(bar))))
BAZ
CL-USER> (baz)
foo: 42
2
```

But, if you're going to do macroexpansion yourself, be sure to preserve [environment arguments](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aad.htm).  In this case, a better definition of `baz` would be:

```
(defmacro baz (&environment env)
  (let ((*foo* 42))
    (macroexpand '(bar) env)))
```